# PyGObject - ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'setuptools_scm'

Tags: python, pygtk, gnome, glade, pygobject

I getting this type errors:

1.

```
pip install PyGObject
E:\Py38venv\lib\site-packages\_distutils_hack\__init__.py:35: UserWarning: Setuptools is replacing distutils.
  warnings.warn("Setuptools is replacing distutils.")
WARNING: Ignoring invalid distribution -ip (e:\Py38venv\lib\site-packages)
WARNING: Ignoring invalid distribution -ensorflow-gpu (e:\Py38venv\lib\site-packages)
WARNING: Ignoring invalid distribution -ip (e:\Py38venv\lib\site-packages)
WARNING: Ignoring invalid distribution -ensorflow-gpu (e:\Py38venv\lib\site-packages)
Collecting PyGObject
  Using cached PyGObject-3.42.0.tar.gz (716 kB)
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... error
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
   command: 'E:\Py38venv\Scripts\python.exe' 'E:\Py38venv\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pep517\in_process\_in_process.py' get_requires_for_build_wheel 'C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpvsjv00bm'
       cwd: C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-7ytkkfbn\pygobject_af461d1bdf452c68be41c4d3dd556117
  Complete output (32 lines):
  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "E:\Py38venv\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pep517\in_process\_in_process.py", line 363, in 
      main()
    File "E:\Py38venv\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pep517\in_process\_in_process.py", line 345, in main
      json_out['return_val'] = hook(**hook_input['kwargs'])
    File "E:\Py38venv\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pep517\in_process\_in_process.py", line 130, in get_requires_for_build_wheel
      return hook(config_settings)
    File "E:\Py38venv\lib\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py", line 162, in get_requires_for_build_wheel
      return self._get_build_requires(
    File "E:\Py38venv\lib\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py", line 143, in _get_build_requires
      self.run_setup()
    File "E:\Py38venv\lib\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py", line 267, in run_setup
      super(_BuildMetaLegacyBackend,
    File "E:\Py38venv\lib\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py", line 158, in run_setup
      exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'), locals())
    File "setup.py", line 313, in 
      du_sdist = get_command_class("sdist")
    File "setup.py", line 59, in get_command_class
      return Distribution({}).get_command_class(name)
    File "E:\Py38venv\lib\site-packages\setuptools\dist.py", line 459, in __init__
      _Distribution.__init__(
    File "E:\Py38venv\lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\dist.py", line 293, in __init__
      self.finalize_options()
    File "E:\Py38venv\lib\site-packages\setuptools\dist.py", line 836, in finalize_options
      for ep in sorted(loaded, key=by_order):
    File "E:\Py38venv\lib\site-packages\setuptools\dist.py", line 835, in 
      loaded = map(lambda e: e.load(), filtered)
    File "E:\Py38venv\lib\site-packages\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 2465, in load
      return self.resolve()
    File "E:\Py38venv\lib\site-packages\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 2471, in resolve
      module = __import__(self.module_name, fromlist=['__name__'], level=0)
  ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'setuptools_scm'
```

After this error pip trying other versions.. and:

2.

```
    Using cached PyGObject-3.30.5.tar.gz (690 kB)
    Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... done
    Requirement already satisfied: pycairo>=1.11.1 in e:\Py38venv\lib\site-packages (from PyGObject) (1.20.1)
    Building wheels for collected packages: PyGObject
    Building wheel for PyGObject (setup.py) ... error
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
    command: 'E:\Py38venv\Scripts\python.exe' -u -c 'import io, os, sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\User\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-qx16gmbe\\pygobject_003a862e82304bd3bead658477ac2e63\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\User\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-qx16gmbe\\pygobject_003a862e82304bd3bead658477ac2e63\\setup.py'"'"';f = getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__) if os.path.exists(__file__) else io.StringIO('"'"'from setuptools import setup; setup()'"'"');code = f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' bdist_wheel -d 'C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-wheel-8xwfz9mj'
       cwd: C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-qx16gmbe\pygobject_003a862e82304bd3bead658477ac2e63\
    Complete output (39 lines):
    running bdist_wheel
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.8
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\pygtkcompat
    copying pygtkcompat\generictreemodel.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\pygtkcompat
    copying pygtkcompat\pygtkcompat.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\pygtkcompat
    copying pygtkcompat\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\pygtkcompat
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\gi
    copying gi\docstring.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\gi
    copying gi\importer.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\gi
    copying gi\module.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\gi
    copying gi\pygtkcompat.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\gi
    copying gi\types.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\gi
    copying gi\_compat.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\gi
    copying gi\_constants.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\gi
    copying gi\_error.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\gi
    copying gi\_gtktemplate.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\gi
    copying gi\_option.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\gi
    copying gi\_ossighelper.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\gi
    copying gi\_propertyhelper.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\gi
    copying gi\_signalhelper.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\gi
    copying gi\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\gi
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\gi\repository
    copying gi\repository\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\gi\repository
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\gi\overrides
    copying gi\overrides\Gdk.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\gi\overrides
    copying gi\overrides\GdkPixbuf.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\gi\overrides
    copying gi\overrides\GIMarshallingTests.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\gi\overrides
    copying gi\overrides\Gio.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\gi\overrides
    copying gi\overrides\GLib.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\gi\overrides
    copying gi\overrides\GObject.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\gi\overrides
    copying gi\overrides\Gtk.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\gi\overrides
    copying gi\overrides\keysyms.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\gi\overrides
    copying gi\overrides\Pango.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\gi\overrides
    copying gi\overrides\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\gi\overrides
    running build_ext
    error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 or greater is required. Get it with "Microsoft C++ Build Tools": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/
    ----------------------------------------
    ERROR: Failed building wheel for PyGObject
    Running setup.py clean for PyGObject
    Failed to build PyGObject
```

I have instaled Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0, etc..

By this looking .whl

[https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#pygtk](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/%7Egohlke/pythonlibs/#pygtk)

Comment: Have you tried installing `setuptools_scm` using the command `pip install setuptools-scm`?

Comment: Not needed coz instaled.